# Passing in an Object to an abstract type's constructor in C++

Tags: c++, abstract-class, c2664

I'm trying to create CnD_Message_Handler of parent type i_MessageHandler. i_MessageHandler constructor takes a i_MessageFactory, another abstract class. CnD_Message_Factory inherits from i_MessageFactory. When I try to instantiate the CnD_Message_Handler, I get the following error:

**error C2664: 'CnD_Message_Handler::CnD_Message_Handler' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CnD_Message_Factory' to 'const CnD_Message_Handler &' 
Reason: cannot convert from 'CnD_Message_Factory' to 'const CnD_Message_Handler'**

From examples online, I believe I'm passing msg_factory correctly. I'm also confused as the constructor requests i_MessageFactory(CnD_Message_Factory) instead of i_MessageHandler(CnD_Message_Handler)

Thanks for any help in advance!

CnD_Device (which instantiates CnD_Message_Factory and CnD_Message_Handler)

```
CnD_Device::CnD_Device(void)
{
  CnD_Message_Factory   msg_factory;                  //Inherited by i_MessageFactory 
  CnD_Message_Handler   msg_handler( msg_factory ); 
}
```

CnD_Message_Factory

```
#include "i_messagefactory.h"

    class CnD_Message_Factory :
      public i_MessageFactory
    {
    public:
      CnD_Message_Factory(void);
      ~CnD_Message_Factory(void);

        /**
         * Creates a message using the stream of data passed in.
         * @param id Id of the message to create.
         * @param stream Data stream to create the message from.
         * @return The created message (which must be returned to the factory by
         * calling the deleteMessage() method, or null if the factory could not
         * create a message.
         */
        Message* createMessage(UInt32 id, const char* stream);

        /**
         * Returns a message to the factory for deleting/recycling.
         * @param msg The message being returned.
         */
        void deleteMessage(Message& msg);
    };
```

CnD_Message_Handler

```
#include "i_messagehandler.h"

class CnD_Message_Handler :
  public i_MessageHandler
{
public:


  CnD_Message_Handler::~CnD_Message_Handler(void);

/**
* Called by a i_MessageDriver object to process a message received.
* @param msg Message to process.
*/
void  CnD_Message_Handler::handleMessage (Message& msg);

/**
* Called by a i_MessageDriver object when an error occurs with an
* interface  The exact type of errors are driver specific.
* @param error The error that occurred.
*/
void  CnD_Message_Handler::handleError (MessageEvent& error);

/**
* Called by the i_MessageDriver object when an event occurs with an
* interface.  The exact type of events are driver specific.
* @param event The event that occurred.
*/
void  CnD_Message_Handler::handleEvent (MessageEvent& event);
};
```

i_MessageHandler

```
 class  i_MessageFactory
{
  public:

    /**
     * Destructor.
     */
    virtual ~i_MessageFactory(void) { }

    /**
     * Creates a message using the stream of data passed in.
     * @param id Id of the message to create.
     * @param stream Data stream to create the message from.
     * @return The created message (which must be returned to the factory by
     * calling the deleteMessage() method, or null if the factory could not
     * create a message.
     */
    virtual Message* createMessage(UInt32 id, const char* stream) = 0;

    /**
     * Returns a message to the factory for deleting/recycling.
     * @param msg The message being returned.
     */
    virtual void deleteMessage(Message& msg) = 0;


  protected:

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    i_MessageFactory(void) { }
};
```

Comment: Fix your code formatting if you want any help.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's wrong with my code formatting? Should I post all my code?

Comment: It might be helpful to you to try to create an example of your problem in a separate cpp -- outside your project. See if you can crystalize the problem to some basic code. Cause I've been playing around with different permutations in a sandbox project based on what you've given and can't get your error to happen.

Comment: @DougT. Thanks for the advice. I'll try to recreate the problem in a separate sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CnD_Message_Handler does not redefine the constructor.

Constructors are not "inherited" in C++03.  You are required to provide constructor arguments for all types you inherit from.  Here is an example.

```
struct Arg {};

struct Foo {
  Foo(Arg arg) {}
  virtual ~Foo() {}
};

struct Bar : public Foo {
  Bar(Arg arg) : Foo(arg) {}
};
```

They can be inherited C++11, but require special syntax.

```
struct Bar : public Foo {
  using Foo::Foo;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I was under the assumption constructors were inherited. That was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`CnD_Message_Handler` has no user defined constructors. Instead its trying to use the copy constructor that the compiler gives you for free, and its telling you it can't convert the factory you passed in to the `const CnD_Message_Handler&` that the compiler-provided copy constructor expects.

Simply define a constructor for `CnD_Message_Handler` to take a factory and instantiate its base class:

```
CnD_Message_Handler(i_MessageFactory& foo) : i_MessageHandler(foo) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the constructors defined by CnD_Message_Handler? You need one that takes a (reference to a) i_MessageFactory (or CnD_Message_Factory). If not, it'll try the constructors generated automagically, like the copy constructor. And I think that is what's happening here.